# Finding all marked element by Grover search(not in superposition)

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Quantum search enables square-sped up search for marked element. When there are multiple maked element, grover search provides only superposition of them. If I want to find all the marked elements, not superposition, I could try this:

1) Do Grover search, get superposition of t marked ele,

2) observe ele space, get one marked ele,

3) remove that ele,

4) goto 1)

This takes time step $O(\sqrt{\frac{N}{t}}+\sqrt{\frac{N-1}{t-1}}+\dots+\sqrt{\frac{N-t+1}{1}})$.

My question is, is this optimal?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54851/24498, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16612/5038.  
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it has been crossposted.